# Array nested struct initialization

Tags: c++, struct, nested, initialization

There have been other posts regarding initialization of array of nested structs.  However, following the given advice elsewhere in Stackoverflow and links to [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) are not helping me resolve an issue.

My context is that I am initializing a number of nested structs in the Vulkan graphics API.

However, in looking at other codes for explanation I ran across the following 'C' initialization (please note that I am adding the defined structs and the code in question)

Vulkan typedefs

```
typedef union VkClearColorValue {
    float       float32[4];
    int32_t     int32[4];
    uint32_t    uint32[4];
} VkClearColorValue;

typedef struct VkClearDepthStencilValue {
    float       depth;
    uint32_t    stencil;
} VkClearDepthStencilValue;

typedef union VkClearValue {
    VkClearColorValue           color;
    VkClearDepthStencilValue    depthStencil;
} VkClearValue;
```

The 'C' code in question

```
    const VkClearValue clear_values[2] = {
            [0] = {.color.float32 = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f}},
            [1] = {.depthStencil = {demo->depthStencil, 0}},
    };
```

The 'C' represenation is legal in C99 and the latest gcc compiler.

However, as I apply this to C++ I get errors.

Going back to rules for aggregate initialization the 'C' represenation should be legal in C++17. However, on compilation I get errors to the effect: **error: expected primary-expression before '.' token**

Clearly I am wrong in my assumption. As such, might anyone provide guidance on how to make it legal in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

> Going back to rules for aggregate initialization the 'C' represenation should be legal in C++17

You assume wrongly, as you have correctly concluded. C++ has had aggregate initialisation since the first standard version, but it doesn't support all initialisations that were added in C99. For example, designated initialisers are not in C++17 at all.

As such, trivial unions can only be initialised with the first member active, like in C89. To activate another member, it must be assigned after initialisation. To do this with a const object, you can use a function.

---

C++20 adds designated initialisers, but even then only subset of C is allowed. Following is well-formed in C++20:

```
const VkClearValue clear_values[2] = {
    {.color {.float32 = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f}}},
    {.depthStencil = {42, 0}},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid form of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) in c++, even though it is in c. In fact, there is a note:

> Note: out-of-order designated initialization, nested designated initialization, mixing of designated initializers and regular initializers, and designated initialization of arrays are all supported in the C programming language, but are not allowed in C++.
>
> ```
> struct A { int x, y; };
> struct B { struct A a; };
> struct A a = {.y = 1, .x = 2}; // valid C, invalid C++ (out of order)
> int arr[3] = {[1] = 5};        // valid C, invalid C++ (array)
> struct B b = {.a.x = 0};       // valid C, invalid C++ (nested)
> struct A a = {.x = 1, 2};      // valid C, invalid C++ (mixed)
> ```